# Writting data in multiple files using Multipleoutputs Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, output, reduce

I had written MapReduce code using Multipleoutputs to write data in multiple files but problem is, it is creating multiple files but not writing data in it why?

```
IN REDUCE
 public MultipleOutputs multipleoutputs;

      public void configure(JobConf job)
            {
              multipleoutputs=new MultipleOutputs(job);                   
            }   
 public void reduce(....)
{
OutputCollector outcollect=multipleoutputs.getCollector("tfidf","1",reporter);                         
                outcollect.collect(new Text(s),new FloatWritable(tfidf));
}
IN DRIVER
 MultipleOutputs.addMultiNamedOutput(conf,"tfidf",TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class,FloatWritable.class);
```

Comment: Are you closing `multipleoutputs` in `cleanup()`?

Answer (score 0):

it is because you need to specify both the file in `MultipleOutputs`, Where you want to write particular output to.

you need to add following line in your driver:

```
MultipleOutputs.addMultiNamedOutput(conf,"SECOND_FILE_NAME",TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class,FloatWritable.class);
```

More detail can be found on [LINK](https://gist.github.com/rstrickland/3763728)

Comment: Can you elaborate you stmt:It is because you need to specify both the filed in MultipleOutputs.and what is "SECOND_FILE_NAME" please elaborate?